# Return TRUE of OR operation Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way that I can get the true value of an OR operation? Something like this?

`=OR(value1, value2, value3) return value that is true`

Comment: Yes, but without seeing your realistic application of this, it's hard to suggest a definitive approach. If you're testing for one of three values in, say, cell A1, this would return `TRUE` if any of the values listed between curly brackets is in A1: `=ArrayFormula(OR(A1={5, 10, 15}))` However, if you're trying to process more than one contiguous cell the same way, if you're testing whether any of three cells holds a certain single value, etc., the formula would differ greatly. The more you can tell (or better yet, show) us, the more likely someone here can help you.

Comment: Like, how can I know which value is true in the OR operation formula? Is there any formula that I can use?

Comment: I'm still not clear on your goal. I know it seems clear to you, because you are looking at all the pieces already and you know your own end goal. But it would really help if you share more about your actual spreadsheet and end goal with us. Or better yet, just share a link to the spreadsheet, explain where you want us to look, where you want the result to show and what that result should be.

Comment: It's *possible* that this is what you mean: `=ArrayFormula(IF(OR(A1={5,10,15}),A1,))` This would return nothing if there is no match, or will return the matching number if one exists in A1.

Comment: I have edited the formula, please let me know. If its still not clear, maybe we can chat

Comment: My formula just above your last comment should work, given what little there is in your post. The volunteer contributors who donate time here do so irregularly. So trying to set up a chat would be difficult. Again, it is better to share a link to a spreadsheet that *shows* realistic data and your end goal, rather than merely trying to *explain* it. But do try to apply the formula last mentioned above; maybe that is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking this question's title literally, the `value` of any true `Or` function is always `True`. However that's probably not what OP is seeking but there's a fundamental misunderstanding that an `Or` function can have *values*. Specifically, this question makes a nonsensical assumption that an `OR` function can have `value1, value2, value3`. An `Or` function contains evaluations that return `true` or `false` -- no third value possible.

To illustrate, what `value` would be returned from this `Or` formula?

`=Or(Not(Isnumber(A1)),len(A1)<5,left(C1,1)="G")`

However, I understand that this is probably specific to some customized situation. The solution is that *some other formula, functionality is needed*. If you're evaluating a single cell (i.e. if cell `A1` has any three values), then [Erik Tyler's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13903283/erik-tyler) proposal of just using an if statement is your answer

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(OR(A1={5,10,15}),A1,))
```

(a less elegant but simplified formula that returns the same would be:  `=if(Or(A1=5,A1=10,A1=15),A1,)`

For finding some true values in a range, there are all kinds of possibilities. However to get you started, you might consider using a filter function combined with boolean logic of `(evaluation1)+(evaluation2)`.

See below formula will list off cell addresses of all true values in this Filter function.

```
=FILTER(Address(ROW(A:A),COLUMN(A:A),4),(A:A=3)+(A:A=5)+(A:A="Hello"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=OR(value1, value2, value3)=TRUE
```

example:

```
=OR(A1=1, A1=2, A1=3)=TRUE
```

[image]